# Cannot access TextBlock properties in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I'm receiving some data from an external device via Bluetooth and I have an event handler which triggers whenever data is received. It's a very basic app where I have a button on the main page which, when pressed, executes the following function:

```
async void BLE_Function()
    {
        //some code to connect to the device

        thermometerCharacteristic.ValueChanged += temperatureMeasurementChanged; //this is where I had a function to the event handler

        await thermometerCharacteristic
            .WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
    }    

public void temperatureMeasurementChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Store the incoming bytes in a byte array called "temperatureData"

        foreach (byte b in temperatureData)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(b.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that I want to display the received bytes in a simple TextBlock which is also on the MainPage just like the above code, but when I write *MyTextBlock.Text = b.ToString()* in the  *foreach* loop, Visual Studio raises an access violation exception. I'm using the same TextBlock in the *BLE_Function()* and over there it works fine, so I don't get why I can't access it from the temperatureMeasurementChanged function. Pasted below are the exception details:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147024891
>   Message=Invalid cross-thread access.
>   Source=System.Windows
>   StackTrace:
>          at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.set_Text(String value)
>          at PhoneApp2.MainPage.displayText(Byte data)
>          at PhoneApp2.MainPage.temperatureMeasurementChanged(GattCharacteristic
>   sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
>   InnerException:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The exception gets raised because you are trying to update the GUI from another thread than the GUI thread. You'll have to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to update the GUI. You can find an example [here](http://weimenglee.blogspot.nl/2013/07/windows-phone-tip-updating-ui-from.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but if it's a threading issue I don't get how I'm able to access the TextBlock directly from the async BLE_Function but not from the even handler function?

Comment: Thats because the BLE_Function is on the GUI thread while the event handler is on a separate thread because it is called asynchronously.